# How to disable protocol checking with gtag.js for new GA4 properties?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

For GA3 analytics.js (Universal Analytics) we can disable protocol checking by `ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null)` ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#disabling_a_task ) but how can we disable it for gtag.js and new GA4 properties G-xxxxxxxxx? In source code of https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js there is checkProtocolTask but in https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js after beautification I do not see something similar and protocol checking is hardcoded `"http:" != k && "https:" != k && (E(29), e.abort())`. With GA4 it is not possible to track webview on file:// protocol.

UPDATE: GA4 indeed doesn't currently provide support for tasks but it should be added to feature request ( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174954288 )

Comment: Maybe a bad idea, but would it work if you host gtag.js locally and strip out the abort? Off course until, google provides a solution

Comment: The Chrome Store policy does not allow bundling minified code.