# How to enable GA4 + GTM in a webview-based hybrid app using a local file path (file://)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a hybrid web app. I tried various methods to plant GTM-based GA4 attribute tags in my service, but the collect function is never called. Help...

1. Based on web view(cordova + reactjs)
2. The screen is composed of react by using the built-in html.
3. Open the page with file:// ..../.../index.html.
4. If you run react in test mode on localhost:3000 and GTM debugging, data is well collected.
5. However, if you build the app and display it as file:// uri, data is not collected.
6. I tried all of the variable handling like checkProtocolTask in the GTM tag setting.

[chrome inspector network capture - http://localhost:3000/?gtm_debug=x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf1bF.png)

Comment: How did you solve that? I also got exact same problem.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178568/how-to-disable-protocol-checking-with-gtag-js-for-new-ga4-properties